# How to create author profile showcase in wordpress

Tags: plugins

I am looking at showcasing author profiles like here:

https://www.speakingtree.in/masters

I have been looking at plugins available but nothing gets close to this layout. If I have to develop this in wordpress, what should be the way forward?

*I have only worked with ready made Themes so far and haven't actually developed new functionality in wordpress.

It would be great to get a direction on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try the [Ultimate Member – User Profile & Membership](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-member/) plugin.

I haven't used their user profile layouts, but they promise to deliver exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: It was very very helpful. Thank you. :)